# Invariant sets in dynamical systems: a characterization.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm currently being introduced to Dynamical Systems in class. Given a set $X$, and maps $S_t \colon X \to X$ for $t \geq 0$, we call $(X,\{S_t\}_{t \geq 0})$ a dynamical (or semi-flow) system if
$$\begin{align*}
(i) & \quad  S_0 = Id_X, \\
(ii) & \quad S_t \circ S_s = S_{t+s}, \quad  \text{for all } t,s \geq 0,
\end{align*}$$
where $\circ$ denotes composition of functions.

I've been asked to prove the equivalence between the following facts, where $D \subset X$ is an arbitraty set:
$$\begin{align*}
(a) & \quad D \text{ is invariant, that is, } S(t)(D) = D \text{ for all } t \geq 0, \\
(b) & \quad D = \bigcup\{u(t) \, : \, t \in \mathbb{R}, \, u \colon \mathbb{R} \to D \text{ solution}\},
\end{align*}$$
where $u \colon \mathbb{R} \to D$ is said to be a solution iff
$$S(t)(u(\tau)) = u(t+\tau), \quad \text{for all } t \geq 0, \, \tau \in \mathbb{R}.$$

I've succesfully proven $(b) \implies (a)$. However, I'm struggling with $(a) \implies (b)$. Note that it is always true that
$$D \supset \bigcup\{u(t) \, : \, t \in \mathbb{R}, \, u \colon \mathbb{R} \to D \text{ solution}\},$$
so Im trying to prove the converse relation by supossing $(a)$.

I know that, in the case of ODEs, the previous equivalence ($S$ can be an evaluation map) is proven by picking a solution of the ODE whose inital condition is an arbitraty point in $D$. Can we do anything similar now? Note that the existence of solution with certain initial conditions isn't obvious for abstract dynamical systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer, as it is proven in Lemma 21.2 of [Sell & You](http://111.90.145.72/get.php?md5=9aad9eefa09c087b6322132a047500e9&key=29CT5GVEAA6L2YVG&mirr=1). They prove that, in invariant sets, there exist solutions with specified initial conditions on the set.